# general question about infinity induction

Tags: induction

I'm a computer science student and during the lecture, the lecturer prove that a set
$\cup_{n=0}^\infty  A_n \subseteq B$ by induction on $n$. i.e $\forall n$  $A_n \subseteq B$

I remember from my mathematic for computer science that kind of induction doesn't hold.

Who wrong?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro it makes sense now thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction allows you to prove (in a certain formal way that often isn't needed in ordinary mathematical proofs) that the infinitely many statements $A_0 \subseteq B,$ $A_1 \subseteq B,$ $A_2 \subseteq B, \, \ldots$ all hold, and hence that $(\forall n)(A_n \subseteq B)$ holds.

However, once you have this, it follows easily from the definition of union that $\cup_{n=0}^\infty  A_n \subseteq B$ holds:

$x \in \cup_{n=0}^\infty  A_n$ implies there exists $N$ such that $x \in A_N$ (by definition of union), and hence from the already established $A_N \subseteq B$ we have $x \in B.$ Thus, we have $x \in \cup_{n=0}^\infty  A_n$ implies $x \in B,$ and hence (by definition of subset) $\cup_{n=0}^\infty  A_n \subseteq B.$

That said, it sounds like the lecturer is confused about induction, because it doesn't establish an "infinite case" from all finite cases. Instead, it simply allows you to "simultaneously in a finite amount of time, so to speak" prove all infinitely many of the finite cases.

Comment: And in particular there's no "infinite case", no $n=\infty$, inherent in the notation $\cup_{n=0}^\infty  A_n \subseteq B$.

Comment: @daniTo: Regarding the comment by David C. Ullrich, the question/answers/comments (which I just now saw) [Rearrangement of Countable Unions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4090774/13130) is especially relevant.